# Error in debug console : "do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, console.log

I have a warning in console only in debug mode which is :

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }": "Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."

(found in <Root>)
```

I have no idea what's going on. It appears only on a click button event to display details information..
You can find the code just below :

```
<template>
  <section>

    <!--Header-->
    <h1 class="section-title">Security Groups</h1>

    <!--Table-->
    <b-table small hover show-empty v-if="securityGroupsLoading === false" head-variant="dark" :items="securityGroups"
      :fields="fields">

      <template v-slot:cell(details)="row">
        <b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails" class="mr-2">
          {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}} Addresses
        </b-button>
      </template>

      <template v-slot:row-details="row">
        <b-card>
          <b-row class="mb-2">
            <div v-if="row.item.addresses.length !== 0"> {{ row.item.addresses }} </div>
          </b-row>
        </b-card>
      </template>

    </b-table>
    <loader v-if="securityGroupsLoading === true" />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import Loader from '@/components/Loader.vue'

export default {
  name: 'SecurityGroups',

  components: {
    Loader,
  },

  props: {
    scopeId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  data: () => ({
    fields: [
      { key: 'name', sortable: true },
      { key: 'type', sortable: true },
      { key: 'description', sortable: true },
      { key: 'tag_association_type', sortable: true },
      { key: 'tags', sortable: true },
      { key: 'usable', sortable: true },
      { key: 'details', sortable: true },
    ],
  }),

  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      securityGroups: state => state.securityGroups.groups,
      securityGroupsLoading: state => state.securityGroups.status.items === 'fetching',
    }),
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.overflowed {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

[Hide / Show button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbHta.png)

I know it's just a warning, and I can remove this warning switching "strict" option to false. But I would understand how can I fix this.

Thanks in advance for your help.
Sereg.

Comment: could you please post you store code? Vuex.store creation

Answer (score 0):

Does your app work well?
if so, and your vuex configuration is somewhat like below:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  actions,
  getters,
  state,
  mutations,
  modules,
  // strict: debug,
})
```

maybe you can remove `restrict` config

Comment: Yes it works well.

I noticed this tips during my research.
So, this warning is not important i guess ?

Thanks for your answer mate :)

Comment: @Seregon I think it's not so important, it will not cause any functionality problem. The warning is for sake of convention I guess, `vuex` hope you `mutate` any state by using a specific `mutation`.